# audit trail with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have fields for audit trail in each table (InsertedBy, InsertedDate, UpdatedBy and UpdatedDate), I build solution to reduce redundant before by override savechange():

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e =>
        e.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added || e.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified))
    {
        Auditing.ApplyAudit(entry, User);
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public class Auditing
{
    public static void ApplyAudit(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, int User)
    {
        Type type = entityEntry.Entity.GetType();
        if (entityEntry.State.ToString() == "Added")
        {
            if (type.GetProperty("InsertedBy") != null)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy").CurrentValue = User;
            }
            if (type.GetProperty("InsertedDate") != null)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("InsertedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
        else if (entityEntry.State.ToString() == "Modified")
        {
            if (type.GetProperty("InsertedBy") != null)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy").IsModified = false;
            }
            if (type.GetProperty("InsertedDate") != null)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("InsertedDate").IsModified = false;
            }
            if (type.GetProperty("UpdatedBy") != null)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("UpdatedBy").CurrentValue = User;
            }
            if (type.GetProperty("UpdatedDate") != null)
            {
                entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the question is:
is using reflection within each entity before modified or added waste in memory and performance ? if yes is there is best practice for this ?
is this another code snippet better in performance or just use reflection also?

```
public static void ApplyAudit(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, long User)
{
    if (entityEntry.State.ToString() == "Added")
    {
        entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy").CurrentValue = User;
        entityEntry.Property("InsertedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
    }
    else if (entityEntry.State.ToString() == "Modified")
    {
        entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy").IsModified = false;
        entityEntry.Property("InsertedDate").IsModified = false;
        entityEntry.Property("UpdatedBy").CurrentValue = User;
        entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

is entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy") uses reflection ?

Comment: Why are you using `State.ToString() == "Modified"` instead of `State == EntityState.Modified`? That surely is a waste of memory

Comment: thanks @Camilo Terevinto I will use this

Comment: `entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy")` doesn't use reflection, it reads the EF metadata. For the rest, maybe you shouldn't reinvent the wheel and look for a third-party library that takes care of auditing in EF., for example: http://entityframework-plus.net/audit (not affiliated).

Comment: thanks @Gert Arnold  if you 100% sure 
 entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy").CurrentValue = User;
not access reflection kindly answer the question and I will be satisfied using this snippet

Comment: I'm 100% sure, but that wasn't your only question. These `type.GetProperty()` call do use reflection abundantly.

Comment: @GertArnold Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210879/does-the-entity-framework-dbentityentry-property-method-use-reflection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection is slow (slow is subjective) and if you want to avoid it, then you need to get rid of such code as below:

```
Type type = entityEntry.Entity.GetType();
if (type.GetProperty("InsertedBy") != null)
```

Even if it was not slow, the code above is still "buggy" because a programmer may mistakenly write `InsertBy` instead of `InsertedBy`. This can easily be avoided with help from the compiler using the approach below.

Use an interface and implement it in all entities that require audit.

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    string InsertedBy { get; set; }
    // ... other properties
}

public class SomeEntity : IAuditable
{
    public string InsertedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Auditor<TAuditable> where TAuditable : IAuditable
{
    public void ApplyAudit(TAuditable entity, int userId)
    {
        // No reflection and you get compiler support
        if (entity.InsertedBy == null)
        {
            // whatever
        }
        else
        {
            // whatever
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you will get compiler support and reflection is not used anymore. I would even go a step further and not pass the `int userId`. I will bring the code for figuring out the `userId` and put it in this class. That way the class is self sufficient and clients do not need to provide it this information.

Usage:

```
var e = new SomeEntity();
var auditor = new Auditor<SomeEntity>();
auditor.ApplyAudit(e, 1); // 1 is userId, I am just hardcoding for brevity
```

Or use it from your context:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var auditables = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e =>
        e.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added || e.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified)
        .OfType<IAuditable>();
    var auditor = new Auditor<IAuditable>();
    foreach (var entry in auditables)
    {
        // 1 is userId, I am just hardcoding for brevity
        auditor.ApplyAudit(entry, 1);
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

This means that all entities who are auditable will need to implement the `IAuditable` interface. EF generates partial classes for your entities but do not modify those partial classes because the next time you run the custom tool, it will be wiped out.

Instead, create another partial class with the same name and implement the `IAuditable`.

```
public partial class SomeEntity : IAuditable {}
```

An even better approach is to create a custom T4 template so it creates the partial class with the code `: IAuditable`. Please see [this article](http://matthidinger.com/archive/2010/02/09/customizing-the-entity-framework-t4-template-suppressing-code-analysis/) for how to do that.

Comment: thanks @CodingYoshi is this mean that I should rewrite each entity partial class with this ?

Comment: @Amir yes or you can change the ef generator to do it for you. But yes, I just create a partial because I do not always need auditing.

Comment: thanks @CodingYoshi for help, last thing I just want to know how I make EF automatically use : IAuditable for each entity without I rewrite the class partially, second is this code snippet use reflection ?
entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy").CurrentValue = User;

Comment: @Amir no it does not use reflection. For the automatic, you need to modify the .tt template. [More here...](http://matthidinger.com/archive/2010/02/09/customizing-the-entity-framework-t4-template-suppressing-code-analysis/)

Comment: @Amir you do not need to do much if your entities already have those properties. All you need to do is add this to your entity class in the .tt file: `YourClass : IAuditable`. That's it!

Comment: yes @CodingYoshi the fields already exists in database thanks for your answer, I just curious is 
entityEntry.Property("InsertedBy").CurrentValue = User
use reflection

Comment: @Amir I am not sure if it uses reflection or not. GertArnold thinks it does not but I am not sure if I agree. However, I mentioned the part that I know for sure uses reflection in my answer.

Comment: @Amir Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210879/does-the-entity-framework-dbentityentry-property-method-use-reflection)